# List Comprehension doesn't work when normal for-loop works fine

Tags: python

I have trouble getting my list comprehension statement to work even though the for-loop works correctly. I'm using it to create a table with reportlab's Table class

```
# Service Table
heading = [('Service', 'Price', 'Note')]

# This doesn't work as in there is no row in the output
heading.append([(s['name'],s['price'],s['note']) for s in services])
table = Table(heading)

# This displays the table correctly
for s in services:
    heading.append((s['name'], s['price'], s['note']))
table = Table(heading)
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use `extend` instead of `append`:

```
heading.extend((s['name'],s['price'],s['note']) for s in services)
```

`append` creates a new element and takes whatever it gets. If it gets a list, it appends this list as a single new element.

`extend` gets an iterable and adds as many new elements as this iterable contains.

```
a = [1, 2, 3]
a.append([4,5])
# a == [1, 2, 3, [4, 5]]

a = [1, 2, 3]
a.extend([4,5])
# a == [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
```

Comment: Thank you. That was spot on.